# Symfony2. Loading security user from database issue

Tags: security, symfony, authentication

Can anyone help me find a way i can use the login feature in a Symfony2 project?. The point is i need this made using a database and symfony's security bundle but i don't have the nickname and password fields. I do have uid and pass but i can't figure out how to make it working.

Btw all tutorials i found contain this kind of code for the security.yml

```
providers:
    user_db:
        entity: { class: Acme\StudentBundle\Entity\User, property: nickname  }
```

is this code:

```
providers:
    user_db:
        entity: { class: Acme\StudentBundle\Entity\Profile, property: uid  }
```

wrong?

The form i use:

```
{% if error %}
    <div>{{ error.message }}</div>
{% endif %}

<form action="{{ path('login_check') }}" method="post">
    <label for="username">User:</label>
    <input id="username" type="text" name="_username" value="{{ last_username }}" />
    <label for="password">Password:</label>
    <input id="password" type="password" name="_password" /> <input type="submit" name="login" />
</form>
```

The error i have is

ContextErrorException: Catchable Fatal Error: Object of class Proxies__CG__\Acme\StudentsManagerBundle\Entity\Student could not be converted to string in C:\xampp\htdocs\symfony.localhost\Symfony\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Firewall\AbstractAuthenticationListener.php line 215

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

### No, it doesn't matter

As you can read in the [Security chapter of Symfony's documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html#loading-users-from-the-database), your concept of a "user" can be anything, as long as it implements the [`UserInterface`](http://api.symfony.com/2.4/Symfony/Component/Security/Core/User/UserInterface.html).

In other words, your entity must `implement` the `UserInterface`, and you must implement the methods that are defined by the interface:

- `getUsername()`
- `getPassword()`
- `getSalt()`
- `getRoles()`
- `eraseCredentials()`

It doesn't matter how you call your 'username' internally (you could call it `username`, `uid`, `foobar`, or whatever), as long as Symfony can get it by calling `getUsername()` - and as long as you define the name of the property in your `security.yml`.

The same goes for the password: the property does not need to be called `password`. It could be `pass`, `secret`, `secretKey` or whatever - as long as the `getPassword()` method returns it, so Symfony can compare it with the password that a user tries to login with.

Comment: Thanks for your time. So this is not the reason for my problem. Can you tell me then whether in the form i use it does matter the value for "id" and "name" attributes. I edited the question too.

Comment: In HTML forms, the `id` is never send to the server, so that won't make a difference. The `name` attribute of your `<input>`s seem to be OK. I don't know what your problem is, so you should give more details about the problem (what is going wrong, do you get an error message, etc.) in your question.

Comment: It seems that the problem is caused by orm's relations to other 2 tables. I have a Profile connected to a Student (OneToOne) and a Profile connected to a AccoutCheck (again OneToOne).

Comment: What is your entity's definition of `getUsername()`? It must return a string, but from your error message I suspect it returns a `Student` object, is that correct?

Comment: I tried to cast the return this way: return (string)$this->cnp; but with no success. The error is "...could not convert to string..."